# OCaml syntax error in the general statement with a module declaration

Tags: syntax, ocaml

```
  1 module type Dictionary = sig
  2     type ('k, 'v) t
  3
  4     val empty : ('k, 'v) t
  5     val insert : 'k -> 'v -> ('k, 'v) t -> ('k, 'v) t
  6     val lookup : 'k -> ('k, 'v) t -> 'v
  7 end
  8
  9 module DictionaryImpl : Dictionary = struct
 10     type ('k, 'v) t = ('k * 'v) list
 11     let empty = []
 12     let insert k v t = (k,v)::t
 13     (*let lookup k t = List.assoc k t*)
 14     let rec lookup k t =
 15         match t with
 16         | [] -> failwith "No data"
 17         | hd::tl ->
 18                if fst hd = k then snd hd
 19                else lookup k tl
 20 end
 21
 22 let _ =
 23     let a = DictionaryImpl.empty in
 24     let b = DictionaryImpl.insert "first" 1 a in
 25     DictionaryImpl.lookup "first" b
 26
```

Please focus on the lines between 22 and 25. 
If I change with the following code, a syntax error is occurred but I don't know why.

```
let a = DictionaryImpl.empty in
let b = DictionaryImpl.insert "first" 1 a in
DictionaryImpl.lookup "first" b
```

The key point that I'm thinking is whether underscore statement is existed or not.
I know that underscore means just ignore receiver variable but I'd like to know what has that I don't know in this context.

Comment: Can you share the exact syntax error, with its line and column number? In general it's a good rule to share exact errors when asking about them :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that

```
let _ =
  let a = DictionaryImpl.empty in
  let b = DictionaryImpl.insert "first" 1 a in
  DictionaryImpl.lookup "first" b
```

is a definition (even if this definition is not binding any variables). Contrarily

```
let a = DictionaryImpl.empty in
let b = DictionaryImpl.insert "first" 1 a in
DictionaryImpl.lookup "first" b
```

is an expression.
Toplevel expressions require to be separated from definitions by `;;`:

```
;; 
let a = DictionaryImpl.empty in
let b = DictionaryImpl.insert "first" 1 a in
DictionaryImpl.lookup "first" b
```

However, this form is not completely idiomatic and lot of people prefer to forego toplevel definitions and use only definitions. For instance, one may write

```
let location="universe"
let () = Format.printf "Hello, %s" location
```

rather than

```
let location="universe"
;;
Format.printf "Hello, %s" location
```

Comment: Can I ask about "Toplevel expression" has what means exactly?

Comment: A toplevel expressions is just an expression that exists outside of any definition. For instance, `0` is a toplevel expression in `module M = struct 0 end`